# Функция работает, только если возвращаемое значение объявить в глобальной области видимости

Tags: javascript, функции, рекурсия, область-видимости

Здравствуйте! Изучаю JavaScript. Попалась такая задачка: Дано число. Нужно складывать его цифры, пока сумма не станет равной однозначному числу (9-ти или меньше). Решить с помощью рекурсии.

Решила следующим образом:

```
var newSum = 0;
function sumNum(num) {
  var sum = 0;
  var numArr = String(num).split('');
  for(var i = 0; i < numArr.length; i++) {
    sum += Number(numArr[i])
  }
  newSum = sum;
   if(sum > 9) {
    num = sum;
    sumNum(num);
  }

  return newSum;
  }
  alert(sumNum(34567));
```

Вопрос: почему функция, пока переменную newSum не объявишь в глобальной области видимости, выдаёт результатом предпоследнее значение newSum, т.е. двузначное число (в моём примере 25). Без этой доп. переменной вообще не смогла решить.

P.S. Возможно, задачка вообще решена не так, как нужно, но готового решения не было. Если есть другие, более правильные решения, покажите, пожалуйста. Буду очень благодарна.

Дубликат вопроса делать не хотела. Искала похожие, просто не нашла.

Comment: Вы использовали 'use strict'?

Comment: Нет, не использовала.

Comment: Более правильное решение - это вообще обойтись без рекурсии и циклов. :)

Comment: _"Нужно складывать его цифры, пока сумма не станет равной однозначному числу (9-ти или меньше)"_ - это исключает рекурсию: данное условие будет выполнено на первой же итерации :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что Вы не используете возвращаeмое значение вызова `sumNum`:

```
if (sum > 9) {
  num = sum;
  sumNum(num); // !!!
}
```

```js
function sumNum(num) {
  var sum = 0;
  var numArr = num.toString().split('');
  for (var i = 0; i < numArr.length; i++) {
    sum += +numArr[i];
  }
  if (sum > 9) {
    sum = sumNum(sum);
  }
  return sum;
}
console.log(sumNum(34567));
```

Comment: А как правильно это сделать?

Comment: Всё правильно. Для рекурсии нужно писать sum = sumNum(sum); а не то что у вас было. Или написать if (sum > 9) {return sumNum(sum);} else {return sum;}

Answer (score 0):

В порядке извращения:

```js
function sumNum(num) {
  return (num + '').length < 2 ? num :
    sumNum(
      (num + '')
      .split('')
      .map(d => +d)
      .filter(d => Number.isInteger(d))
      .reduce((s, i) => s + i)
    )
}

console.log([0, 1, -1, 8, 9, 10, 99, 123456, -654321].map(num => sumNum(num)).toString());

console.log(sumNum(Math.PI)); // ;)
```

Comment: Всем большое спасибо. Очень помогли.